# Increase/Change Bootstrap3 column size?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've three col-md-4 in a row.

- Then I drop 2 columns with javascript
- Now 1 column left in that row.
- I would like to say this
  column, because it is alone in the row that it should get more width
  (or transform to a col-md-7).

Code:

```
.container
  .row
    .col-md-4#first 1. column
    .col-md-4#second 2. column
    .col-md-4#third 3. column

:javascript
  $("#first").remove();
  $("#third").remove();
```

My only idea is to copy the contents of the column, create a new column and insert the content there. Is there any smarter solution for that?

Comment: Could you just change the only column to col-md-7 `$("#second").removeClass("col-md-7"); $("#second").addClass("col-md-7");`  I don't know whether this can be done in one command

Comment: you're right `$("#second").removeClass("col-md-4").addClass("col-md-7");` does it! Thanks!

Comment: Great! I’m glad to hear it worked well for you

Answer (score 0):

With help from Yang I found out that `.removeClass` and `.addClass` let the column grow in a dynamic behavoir.

```
$("#second").removeClass("col-md-4").addClass("col-md-7");
```